# php: exploding strings

Tags: php, string, explode

I am trying to get a simple array from a string.

Ej. [position] => ???? [ heading] => ??? [ pitch] => ??? [ zoom] => ???

But for some reason I get the following error:

> **Notice**: Undefined index: heading on line 21

**Here is the PHP code:**

```
<?php
$mysql_data= 
"position: 34.032616, -118.286564|
heading: -159.50240187408838|
pitch: 0|
zoom: 2";


$pov = explode("|", $mysql_data);
foreach($pov as $key)
{
    $element = explode(": ", $key);
    $pov[ $element[0] ] = $element[1];
}
unset($element);


//Testing echoes
print_r($pov);
echo "\n";
echo $pov['heading'];
?>
```

Also, is there a simpler way to do this in a single go and skip foreach all together?

BTW: I do not need key's 0,1..etc, only labeled ones like 'heading','zoom',etc

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a regular expression that solves the same problem with less hacks than `parse_str()` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way to do it without `foreach()`, assuming that there are no newlines in the input string:

```
$str = 'position: 34.032616, -118.286564|heading: -159.50240187408838|pitch: 0|zoom: 2';
$str = str_replace(array('|',':'), array('&','='), $mysql_data);

parse_str($str, $pov);

print_r($pov);
/*
Array
(
    [position] =>  34.032616, -118.286564
    [heading] =>  -159.50240187408838
    [pitch] =>  0
    [zoom] =>  2
)
*/
```

If there are newlines in the input string, change the rules in the `str_replace` args.

```
str_replace(array("\r\n","\n",'|',':'), array('','','&','='), $mysql_data);
```

Comment: is there any difference between `$mysql_data = trim($mysql_data);` and adding `\n` to the `str_replace()` function?

Comment: `trim()` will remove the whitespaces from both ends of `$mysql_data`. While the code above doesn't really care with whitespaces. It just converts the string to array the way you want.

Comment: I had no idea you could use str_replace in combination with arrays :O I learned a new thing today. BTW, Thank you! Your answer covers both of my questions and a bit more =)

Answer (score 6):

There's a newline in front of `heading`.

Inside your loop you should `trim()` the array key (and value just in case):

```
$pov[ trim($element[0]) ] = trim($element[1]);
```

**Update**

A simple regular expression will also take care of this:

```
$s = <<<EOM
position: 34.032616, -118.286564|
heading: -159.50240187408838|
pitch: 0|
zoom: 2
EOM;

if (preg_match_all('/(\w+):([^|]+)/', $s, $matches)) {
    $pov = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
```

Btw: don't use `parse_str` hacks, that function is meant for data that's already properly URL encoded and quite honestly is the wrong tool for the job.